# Python reading from file stops abruptly

Tags: python, file

I am reading from a text file of 750 lines. This is my code:

```
x = 0
with open(path.join(_path, _filename), 'rU') as f:
    for line in f:
        print x, line
        x += 1
```

Process stops always at line 713. This is the print-out:

```
709 83968|10-07-2014 04:00:00|4607|8059|JNBO=4Y8%_LLLC*6K/&:).|"LC[IB91/""L+E>\B%3K#VM&"|"PHS[D_(""%OUR3\6VH^<!M"""|74005|57009|0|0
710 83969|10-07-2014 04:00:00|1391|8059|I?WWB^!KFY3EY\QD50H/.0|KSN<U$-&?*END,=GHL3<N%|AHC\UJ70%)0/:2K&7A22F&|74005|57009|0|0
711 84349|10-07-2014 04:00:00|36518|8059|C$>P!_8!TTDJK*KE+U=Y@.|O!!LB_I2+ARD]W!)U_S56)|"A3$(74Q2\74_/2'3;<\%5"""|74005|74004|0|0
712 80354|10-07-2014 04:00:00|7267|8059|K@A#JK4LC;M_-O!<#.95B/|N8#2R&=B[4]D7KOD\3`CI#|"B,[`Z=K$*#36;7""L;9^,6("|74005|57009|0|0
713 76910|10-07-2014
```

And this is the excerpt from the file:

```
83968|10-07-2014 04:00:00|4607|8059|JNBO=4Y8%_LLLC*6K/&:).|"LC[IB91/""L+E>\B%3K#VM&"|"PHS[D_(""%OUR3\6VH^<!M"""|74005|57009|0|0
83969|10-07-2014 04:00:00|1391|8059|I?WWB^!KFY3EY\QD50H/.0|KSN<U$-&?*END,=GHL3<N%|AHC\UJ70%)0/:2K&7A22F&|74005|57009|0|0
84349|10-07-2014 04:00:00|36518|8059|C$>P!_8!TTDJK*KE+U=Y@.|O!!LB_I2+ARD]W!)U_S56)|"A3$(74Q2\74_/2'3;<\%5"""|74005|74004|0|0
80354|10-07-2014 04:00:00|7267|8059|K@A#JK4LC;M_-O!<#.95B/|N8#2R&=B[4]D7KOD\3`CI#|"B,[`Z=K$*#36;7""L;9^,6("|74005|57009|0|0
76910|10-07-2014 04:00:00|49425|8059|"D'A\<(%N?FS\ARP??""CJ0."|"H`]8#E^"")T""P""0':]OZ%V*"|"F'),+F`6WU?UT>""=K<#PC."|74005|74004|0|0
84356|10-07-2014 04:00:00|3236|8059|"GT&]S-7<A%MSBO>""Z2(T%+"|F6YDP\;O@_4?BW!1VIC1O!|P/O/9W)(YJ&+:\=HK)*OA$|74005|55427|0|0
89539|10-07-2014 04:00:00|1113|8059|"GP',L]BZVELBMY`6(&4%^%"|"L2`GSTCJ:^.\G\I:'SQ*T'"|"JD^28<IKKQ6=%7V/FX6-['"|74005|74004|0|0
```

line 713 is the 3rd from the bottom in this fragment.

I guess it thinks that it reaches the end (maybe a EOF character?).

Any ideas what is wrong with the file?

UPDATE: This is the whole file > http://dpaste.com/3CCGZY9

UPDATE 2: This is a screenshot from vim : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2423935/err.jpg (line that cause the problem is highlighted)

UPDATE 3: It seems that pasting back from dpaste solves the problem. However, I cannot do anything for that because the file prior to parsing is downloaded from an FTP server. This the code I am using to download it from the ftp:

```
try:
    connection = FTP("<SERVER_IP>")
    connection.login("<username>", "<pass>")
    connection.cwd("dir1")
    filenames = connection.nlst()
    filenames = sorted(filenames)
    for name in filenames:
        exists = path.isfile(path.join(_path, name))
        if not exists:  # fetch it!!
            localfile = open(path.join(_path, name), 'wb')
            connection.set_pasv(False)
            connection.retrbinary("RETR " + name,
                                  localfile.write, 1024)
except all_errors as e:
    log.error("Cannot connect to FTP Server because %s" % repr(e))
```

UPDATE 4: This is the actual file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2423935/source.txt and this is the hex dump: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2423935/hex.txt

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using the code and input you have provided. All lines are read and `print`ed correctly.

Comment: Works fine for me, using Python 2.7.6 on Linux.  What are you using?

Comment: The same. Linux and python 2.7. There are 750 lines of the same type in the file. Can it be a memory problem?

Comment: If it was a memory problem it would crash in a different way. And without loading all file in memory, looks completely impossible.

Comment: Is your program finished? Will it be that the output is cached?

Comment: @WKPlus: that's probably the issue; the last print is still buffered. `sys.stdout.flush()` could help here.

Comment: yes the program exits normally. Other files of the same type are read even up to line 4000 (some files are bigger and some are smaller). This is the only file that is giving me this.

Comment: By the way, instead of using the `x` variable to keep track of line number, you can just use `for x, line in enumerate(f):`

Comment: For debugging, I will use `os.mkdir(x)` to make sure whether the program is abrupted or output is cached.

Comment: Thanks @ikaros45. I didn't want the `x`. I added that only for debugging purposes for that file one.

Comment: Could you show a hex dump of the beginning of the file, to be sure what line endings it has, and also a hex dump of the end (vim could be nice for that ...)

Comment: Thanks for sending a vim image, but I needed a hex dump (`:%!xxd`)

Comment: Where is the output printed to? This might be a terminal's issue. Try redirecting `stdout` to a file to eliminate this possibility.

Comment: Something is strange : the file hex.txt begins with a header line, and and file in dpaste has not. Have you anything else to skip first line, or ... because **I cannot reproduce** (details below my answer) ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta thanks for the notice. For some reason the header was missing. I corrected the problem. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I coulnd't reproduce the problem on the data provided. However, as a guess, maybe it has something to do with buffering? Then, try:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

After print. I'm pointing in that direction because it doesn't show any error.

Otherwise please try to provide whole file in unchanged form (eg upload it somewhere).

Comment: Thanks. It is still the same, however. I added the flush() just after the print command. I still get the same output.

Comment: Interesting thing is, I still cannot reproduce the problem - for me it displays all 739 lines. I'm wondering if there is a non printable character in your file, that gets lost when you paste it to dpaste - could you try getting the file from dpaste and running it against your program? Maybe there is a difference between the files - then it will be easy to find.

Comment: @xpanta: That doesn't look like the whole file. Also it would be better to add a link to the actual file, not to it filtered though dpaste.

Comment: @vetham. you were right. Pasting the text file right from dpaste is working! How is that?

Comment: @martineau, this is the whole file.

Comment: @xpanta Please try to provide an actual file - not the copy/pasted version but the file itself. The problem is, that there are some unprinted characters in the file, which are lost when you copy it.

Comment: I tried processing the full file on my environment (linux) and it still works. I think the problem might be described on [this page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails). Can you try:  >>> import locale
>>> locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
And check if the result is utf-8?

Answer (score 0):

The file is made under Windows, and processed under Linux. There may be many problems, that a simple copy-paste from a *displayed* image of the file may solve, caused by non-printable characters.

The end of line is normally correctly processed by any version of Python, by I was thinking of native UTF16 text files on Windows (with BOM markers) or more probably of end of file (`^Z`) characters that some programs used to add (and some still do) as a reminiscence of old CP-M operating system (dinosaurs used it ...). It can easily be fixed, but not without an exact copy of the file or hex dumps.

Comment: I added the actual and the hex versions of the file. Hope that helps.

Comment: @xpanta: Fine, the file has Windows end of line, no end of file character, but it has a UTF8 BOM in the beginning. No I can try to reproduce ...

Comment: @xpanta: unfortunately, I cannot reproduce. I put the BOM in beginning of file and using Python 2.7.6 on FreeBSD 9 all works fine. Just to confirm, md5 of the tested file is `aa310f96a3187125142d2f3681791f52`